# django with angular js vs jus javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, google-cloud-platform

I want to make a lightening-fast web application and am wondering about the best way to implement it. It's a drawing app that will need support for vector graphics, but it will use a database to store data in user accounts. Here's how I'm breaking it down in MVC terminology:

- Controller: Django, hosted on GCP Python app engine
- Model: CloudSQL
- View: AngularJS

I'm wondering if a Javascript/JQuery approach would be better, since I could have Django handle the database operations and am worried that I'll just be adding overhead with Angular.

*I'd welcome any thoughts.*

Answer (score 0):

Once you use Javascript framework such as Angular.js and React.js. Your backend and frontend becomes totally isolated. First thing you should do it you gotta make your django REST API. Build your logics to do the vector graphic in your django REST API and build your angular.js app in away that it will "consume" your REST API services.

For the second question, it is depending on your architecture design. If your application is going to be DOM-driven, use jQuery since still jquery still provides lots of UI stuff. However, if it's going to be data-driven and you will use Javascript to organize and display the data in efficient way, choose Angular.js.

Please leave a comment if you have more questions. Thanks!